# save different date format into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a datetime mysql column.
I send an insert command with an date format:

```
YYYYMMDDTHHiiss
```

The date value was correctly stored as date time format of mysql.
Is this the correct way or would it be best practice to send my date in format?:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss
```

Thanks !

Comment: Use the `str_to_date()` function to convert your format to `DATETIME`.

Comment: doesn't really matter the incoming format as you would/should be validating it, which then you can correctly format a successful parsed/validated date into the correct mysql format

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html

> MySQL recognizes DATETIME and TIMESTAMP values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' or 'YY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' format.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either 'YYYYMMDDhhmmss' or 'YYMMDDhhmmss' format, provided that the string makes sense as a date.
> - As a number in either YYYYMMDDhhmmss or YYMMDDhhmmss format, provided that the number makes sense as a date.